# How to properly serve a dinamic image with Node and Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having many problems to achive what I'm trying:

I want to request an image from this URL `http://tapas.clarin.com/tapa/1990/02/22/19900222_thumb.jpg` and show it in the view but I'm getting this showned in the view instead:

[image]

What's the proper way of achieving what I want ?

This is my code:

```
const app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var rp = require('request-promise');
const fs = require('fs')


var url = 'http://tapas.clarin.com/tapa/1990/02/22/19900222_thumb.jpg'

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   rp(url)
  .then(image => res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg').send(image))
  .catch(err => res.send(err));
})

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: You need to set content type. `res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg').send(image)`

Comment: Ok, now it's showing like a black screen, not the image I want to serve :(

Comment: this link might help  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772394/how-to-upload-display-and-save-images-using-node-js-and-express"

Comment: Not really, I've seen it but that is for a static image and with no promises ! Thanks anyway

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337841/how-to-display-image-from-http-request-to-external-api-with-node-js    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301227/external-api-calls-with-express-node-js-and-require-module

Comment: Please try above links once you may find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting back a string from request-promise, not a buffer.Setting encoding: null, will get you a buffer which you can send back.

```
const app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var rp = require('request-promise');


var options = {
    url: 'http://tapas.clarin.com/tapa/1990/02/22/19900222_thumb.jpg',
    encoding: null
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   rp(options)
  .then(image => {
      return res.end(image,'binary');
  })
  .catch(err => res.send(err));
})

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```